# Compile Jasper reports from Maven with ant task?

Tags: maven-2, jasper-reports

How can I compile jrxml jasper files using Maven and JRAntCompileTask ant task? I tried using a maven plugin for compiling jasper reports files but it's still in beta, and it caused me many problems. I'd like to see the configuration in pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I compile jrxml jasper files using Maven and JRAntCompileTask ant task?

You can use the custom Ant Tasks with the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/). See the example provided in [Using tasks not included in Ant's default jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/customTasks.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try jasperreports-maven-plugin, that way you don't have to use ant, [Here is an example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jasperreports-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example that solves problems with Eclipse m2e reporting errors with maven configuration, has reports neatly set in a separate folder and has classpath configured.

Just be sure to put your .jrxml files in src/main/jasperreports folder and you're set - every time you change the report, .jasper files will be regenerated.

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <jasperreports.version>5.0.0</jasperreports.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0-beta-2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <!-- Include the generated reports in classpath -->
            <directory>target/jasper</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <!--Folder with .jrxml report files -->
            <directory>src/main/jasperreports</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Folder where compiled reports will be generated -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jasper</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```